# One Resource belongs to two parent resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

in routes.rb

```
resources :restaurants do
  collection do
    get 'nearby'
  end

  resources :tickets
end

resources :users do
  resources :tickets
end
```

If my controller, I can differentiate the parent resources

```
if params[:user_id].present?
  @collection = User.find(params[:user_id])
else
  @collection = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
end
@ticket = @collection.tickets.new
```

but how can I differentiate, for example, path helper?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [polymorphic_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html#method-i-polymorphic_path).